# Postgresql's QueryExecutor hanging indefinitely at `receiveChar()` for query which has successfully completed

Tags: java, database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm facing a weird issue where Postgres seemingly isn't sending a reply to my client code even after successfully completing the query. As such, it hangs around indefinitely in the blocking `receiveChar()` call waiting for something that never arrives. Note, this is not an intermittent behavior, it's happening *every time* we attempt to run the query through Java.

[Here's the relevant code where it's blocking](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L2113).

```java
    boolean doneAfterRowDescNoData = false;

    while (!endQuery) {
      c = pgStream.receiveChar();   // <- blocks here and never comes back 
      switch (c) {
        case 'A': // Asynchronous Notify
          receiveAsyncNotify();
          break;
```

This occurs while trying to move about 2m records from one table into another. e.g.

```sql
insert into target_table (
   select * from blah where xyz
)
```

### How I checked it was not the query itself still working and is actually the client hanging

The query itself happily completes, which I verified multiple ways.

1. `select count(*)` on the target table and finding the transferred data
2. verifying that no database activity remains.

Here's the Performance tab of RDS showing nothing going on.

[image]

Similarly, this was confirmed in the database itself via

```sql
select relname,
       psa.pid,
       psa.application_name,
       l.granted,
       query,
       l.*,
       psa.*
from pg_locks l
         inner join pg_stat_activity psa ON (psa.pid = l.pid)
         left outer join pg_class c ON (l.relation = c.oid)
```

which shows no activity going on. And yet, the `receiveChar()` call still sits there waiting.

### Logs show no timeouts, connection drops, or anomalies

Last entries in the log are the query and then the dump of the params.

```
2021-09-18 03:16:52 UTC:72.21.198.65(10130):foo@postgres:[20850]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'foo', $2 = 'bar'
```

Nothing after this. The `insert` finishes. I can see the results in the DB. All the while, the debugger is still hanging out at the `receiveChar()` line waiting for a response from Postgres.

Plz halp...

#### Extra Info

- I'm using the `postgresql = 42.18` version of the Postgres java library.
- I'm the only client of the database.
- there are no errors in the log.
- The `insert` executes without issue if I `limit` it to smaller sets. However, when doing the full 2m, which is still pretty small potatoes, it does this hanging behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the query executor waiting, but the backend in the main processing loop. The previous statement is done, now it is waiting for the client to send the next command. You can verify that by looking at the `wait_event_type` and `wait_event` in the corresponding `pg_stat_activity` entry.

You are looking at the wrong thing. It seems to be the database client that is hanging rather than sending a next statement.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I do now see that after the query completes `pg_stat_activity` shows a `wait_event` of `ClientRead`. Forgive my ignorance, but... how would I debug this further? We've stripped our test code down to just a bare-bones `main` method and the `insert` (via JOOQ). Would this be a library bug...?

Comment: What is the misbehavior you are trying to debug?

Comment: I'm still at a total loss as to why it starts waiting on the client, only when (a) running through Java rather than, say, psql, and (b) only does the ClientRead wait thing when running for the full ~2m record query (running for smaller sets using `limit` doesn't cause the same behavior)